# Flutter how to link arrays by ids

Tags: flutter, dart

I have data like this

```
 var sendlocal = [
  {
    "firstName": "tree",
    "lastName": "tree",
    "relativeEmail": "tree@gmail.com",
    "relativeType": 0,
    "subid": 1,
    "subRelatives": [
      {
        "firstName": "julia2",
        "lastName": "Michle",
        "relativeEmail": "test@hotmail.com3",
        "relativeType": 2,
        "subid": 2,
        "subRelatives": [
          {
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "bravo",
            "relativeEmail": "johny@gmail.com",
            "relativeType": 1,
            "subRelatives": [],
            "subid": 3,
          },
          {
            "firstName": "simith",
            "lastName": "bravo",
            "relativeEmail": "johny@gmail.com",
            "relativeType": 1,
            "subRelatives": [],
            "subid": 4,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "firstName": "julia3",
        "lastName": "Michle",
        "relativeEmail": "test3@hotmail.com",
        "relativeType": 2,
        "subRelatives": [],
        "subid": 5,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

And as per below answer(Thanks) I create a function like this

```dart
  getIndexFromNestedList(List<dynamic> mapValue) {
    if (mapValue != null) {
      for (var relation in mapValue) {
        print(relation['subid']);
        print(relation['relativeEmail']);

        if (relation['subRelatives'] != null) {
          for (var subRelation in relation['subRelatives']) {
            print({relation['subid'], subRelation['subid']});
            // graph.addEdge(relation['subid'], subRelation['subid']); //like this
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
              getIndexFromNestedList(relation['subRelatives']);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and pass data like this

```
var check = getIndexFromNestedList(relatives);
```

And I getting responses like this

```
flutter: {1, 2}
flutter: {1, 3}
4flutter: {2, null}
```

What Expected is {2,3} {2,4} and so on if sub relative also have sub relative. But it's showing null don't know why when it's going to sub relatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested for loop to get those values like the following and resend the loop to the method to get the nested values

```
getIndexFromNestedList(List<dynamic> mapValue) {
  for (var relation in mapValue) {
    if (relation['sub'] != null) {
      for (var subRelation in relation['sub']) {
        print({relation['id'], subRelation['id']});//you can add it directly to the map here.
        graph.addEdge(relation['id'], subRelation['id']);//like this
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds:1), (){//future is added to finish the first loop then to enter into the inner loops.
          getIndexFromNestedList(relation['sub']);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

//OUTPUT
{1, 2}
{1, 6}
{2, 3}
{2, 5}
{2, 3}
{2, 5}
{3, 4}
{3, 4}
{3, 4}
{3, 4}
```

you can use this method to set the values into the graph

```
getIndexFromNestedList(reList);
```

**EDIT**
for the current structure you can check if the first value is not null before you access its children like the following

```
getIndexFromNestedList(List<dynamic> mapValue) {
  if (mapValue != null) {
    for (var relation in mapValue) {
      print(relation['subid']);
      print(relation['relativeEmail']);

      if (relation['subRelatives'] != null) {
        for (var subRelation in relation['subRelatives']) {
          print({relation['subid'], subRelation['subid']});
          // graph.addEdge(relation['subid'], subRelation['subid']); //like this
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
            getIndexFromNestedList(relation['subRelatives']);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit on 7AUG**

In the question again you missed to check if its a null value and if length is greater than 0. also you are passing `relatives` to the method.. The list name was`sendlocal`

Here is the updated method with length check too

```
  getIndexFromNestedList(List mapValue) {
    if (mapValue != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < mapValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapValue[i]['subRelatives'].length; j++) {
          Map subList = mapValue[i]['subRelatives'][j];
          print({mapValue[i]['subid'], subList['subid']});
          if (subList['subRelatives'].length > 0) {
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
              getIndexFromNestedList(mapValue[i]['subRelatives']);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

//Output
flutter: {1, 2}
flutter: {1, 5}
flutter: {2, 3}
flutter: {2, 4}
```

Tested this multiple times and removed all duplicates too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its helps but I have edited question with my real data don't know why its stuck after 1,2 to 1,6 on sub arrays. If you can help on this.

Comment: print(relation['relativeEmail']). Not all data list has this value.. put it inside a try catch

Comment: but just printing relativeEmail we are using subid and all list have each subid

Comment: Updated my answer with condition check for null. Please use this method

Comment: See section Edit on 7AUG

Answer (score 1):

I got your answer as per your requirement, maybe this helpful for you

```
void main(){
  var check =getIndexFromList(sendlocal);
}

getIndexFromList(List sendlocal) {
    if (sendlocal != null) {
      for (var relation in sendlocal) {
        print('subid:- ${relation['subid']}');
        print('relativeEmail:- ${relation['relativeEmail']}');

        if (relation['subRelatives'] != null && relation['subRelatives'].length > 0) {
          for (var subRelation in relation['subRelatives']) {
            
            //its your required response
            print({relation['subid'], subRelation['subid']});
            
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2), () {
              getIndexFromList(relation['subRelatives']);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


var sendlocal = [
  {
    "firstName": "tree",
    "lastName": "tree",
    "relativeEmail": "tree@gmail.com",
    "relativeType": 0,
    "subid": 1,
    "subRelatives": [
      {
        "firstName": "julia2",
        "lastName": "Michle",
        "relativeEmail": "test@hotmail.com3",
        "relativeType": 2,
        "subid": 2,
        "subRelatives": [
          {
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "bravo",
            "relativeEmail": "johny@gmail.com",
            "relativeType": 1,
            "subRelatives": [],
            "subid": 3,
          },
          {
            "firstName": "simith",
            "lastName": "bravo",
            "relativeEmail": "johny@gmail.com",
            "relativeType": 1,
            "subRelatives": [],
            "subid": 4,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "firstName": "julia3",
        "lastName": "Michle",
        "relativeEmail": "test3@hotmail.com",
        "relativeType": 2,
        "subRelatives": [],
        "subid": 5,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The response is something like that,

```
 subid:- 1
    relativeEmail:- tree@gmail.com
    {1, 2}
    {1, 5}
    subid:- 2
    relativeEmail:- test@hotmail.com3
    {2, 3}
    {2, 4}
    subid:- 5
    relativeEmail:- test3@hotmail.com
    subid:- 2
    relativeEmail:- test@hotmail.com3
    {2, 3}
    {2, 4}
    subid:- 5
    .............
    .............
```